# Rearrage divs to the right when max height reached

Tags: javascript, css

I have a ton of little div's getting generated by php that need to form columns when they reach the max-height of their parent div.

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
     ...
</div>
```

They are all 22*22 squares and need to stack in a div with max-height of 115px, infinite width with bottom and right margins of 1. When 5 formed a column, the 6th needs to be at the right of the 1st.

I read elsewhere this can only be achieved through js, how would I go about doing this? And is it really not possible through css without adding a column system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.parent .child:nth-child(6n) {
    float: left
}
```

You might need to try some other values instead of 6 if 6 does not work.